# Use PDO's bind param multiple times as variable

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I was searching over the internet and i didnt find any solution.

Lets say i want to use one paramerer in PDO multiple times.

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `user_names` ON `users`.`id`=`user_names`.`id`
WHERE `user_names`.`name` LIKE CONCAT('%', ? ,'%') OR `users`.`name` LIKE CONCAT('%', ? ,'%')
```

How can i avoid to use `?` two times ? I am looking for something like this:

```
SELECT ? AS `search_name`, *
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `user_names` ON `users`.`id`=`user_names`.`id`
WHERE `user_names`.`name` LIKE CONCAT('%', `search_name` ,'%') OR `users`.`name` LIKE CONCAT('%', `search_name` ,'%')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can join an extra subselect that contains the parameter value or (like I do below) the complete search string.

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `user_names` ON `users`.`id`=`user_names`.`id`
CROSS JOIN (SELECT CONCAT('%', x.name, '%') as SearchString) x
WHERE `user_names`.`name` LIKE x.SearchString OR `users`.`name` LIKE x.SearchString
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in the normal mode. The only way to get around this is to use named parameters with emulation mode turned on (PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES).

I, however, typically advise against doing this though and just recommend using multiple bindParam statements using named parameters instead of question marks. So you can use :searchname1 and :searchname2 both connected with the same POST/GET variable.